# Does querySelectorAll's onClick method attach to all of the elements?

Tags: dart

For example,

```
querySelectorAll(".className").onClick.listen(....)
```

Does the above onClick listener attach itself to all of the elements with the specified class name or do I have to use a forEach and then add a listener?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will, and here is a snippet of code where 2 buttons are being attached with an onclick listener

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e6453ef557574fb8f8e830acc2be6616